# Cannot re-enter a color once a image has been chosen JS

Tags: javascript, html

My website currently changes background colour when a user enters there desired color, although I am trying to allow my user to enter in a desired keyword that will change the background to the image designated with that word. For example, if the user inputs 'tree' the background will change to trees, I am doing this for only a few keywords and I'm using if statements to change the background.

The problem is when a user inputs one of these keywords such as 'tree' they are unable to change the background colour again and are stuck on the background of trees. I want the user to be able to re-input a colour and the background will change to the input.

[Video of the bug (Streamable)](https://streamable.com/coo86)

[Live link (Codepen)](https://codepen.io/JacquesAndre/pen/KoramR)

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="userinput" class="userinputclass" id="textinput" placeholder='Enter Your color/hex/rgb here...' onkeypress="process(event, this)" />
<input type="button" value="Change Color" onclick="changeColor();"/>
```

JS

```
function process(e) {
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (code == 13) { //Enter keycode
    changeColor();
  }
}
function changeColor() {
  var input = document.getElementById('textinput').value;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = input;

  if (input == '') {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = rand;
  }
  if (input == 'tree') { 
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg/220px-Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg')";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting null for background for any entry that don't match with 'tree' will solve your problem. You will be able to enter value for color again.

```
if (input == 'tree') { 
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('...')";
} else {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you're setting 2 different properties 'backgroundColor' and 'backgroundImage'.

What I think you're missing is that a set 'backgroundImage' property will override any 'backgroundColor' property.

You should be able to set 'backgroundImage' back to '' or null and then the 'backgroundColor' should be visible again.

try adding something like:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = null;
```

to the top of your changeColor function to make sure that it is always reset.

Answer (score 0):

You are not deleting the background image once the tree image is set.

```
  function changeColor() {
      var input = document.getElementById('textinput').value;
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = null;
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = null;
       if (input == 'tree') { 
          document.body.style.backgroundImage = 
                 "url(keep ur link)";
           } else {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = input;
        }
       }
```